# Как правильно задать контроллеры для представлений в laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Имеется следующая структура шаблонов:

1. resources/views/common/header.blade.php
2. resources/views/common/home.blade.php
3. resources/views/common/search.blade.php
4. resources/views/common/footer.blade.php

В *home.blade.php* делаю подключение `header` и `footer`:

```
@extends('common.header')

@extends('common.footer')
```

Планируется, что в `header` будут подключены модули: меню, поиска, языков, валют и другие.
В `footer` так же планируется подключение и вывод модулей.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно в `laravel` подключать контроллеры в пределах одного представления?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю что хотите сделать.

1. Создаете маршрут: Route::get('/admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
   AdminController - Нужный контроллер
   index - функция в котроллере
2. В функции index описываете нужные действия и в конце вызываете нужное представление

   `public function index()
   {
       //Действия
       $data1 = ...
       $data2 = ...
       return view('common.home', ['data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2]);
   }`

Если нужно реализовать вывод или не вывод какого-либо блока то в шаблоне делать проверку на заранее передаваемое значение(флаг)
 Пример вывода ошибок:
`@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <a href="#" class="close" style="text-decoration: none;" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif`

п.с. Как я понял, не рекомендуется плодить очень много подключений и подключений в подключениях, главное не переборщить)

Comment: Да, так и делаю. Только не отрабатывает. А не отрабатывает конкретно включение действия. Например, мне нужно, чтобы header внутри себя имел 4 дополнительных представления, а именно search, currency, login, menu. За каждым из этих представлений будет закреплен контроллер.

Comment: И вот вопрос заключается именно в том, как мне в контроллере header передать на view('header', $data), где $data['search'], $data['currency'], $data['menu'] будут вызывать свои view.

Comment: Пробовал так: $data['menu'] = view:make('menu'); но тогда вызов происходит только представления, без контроллера. А если делаю так: $menu = new Menu (); $data['menu']  = $menu->view(); тогда выводит просто текст html, без декодирования в html. (декодировать пробовал не включается)

Comment: Нашел на ларакасте инструкцию работы с view::composer но не могу понять конкретно одного момента. Там задают view:composer в Providers->boot(), как глобальная функция и на callback сбрасывают функцию вызова $menu->view($data); но демонстрация идет только для одного подключаемого блока.

Comment: И вот собственно говоря и встал вопрос, а правильно ли я думаю на счет подключений представлений в представлениях и т.д. И как лучше это сделать, чтобы систему не нагружать и было читабельно. \